# BASH: Substituting a variable inside a variable during echo

Tags: bash

I explained my question in the comments:

```
VAR=
INS="Installing $VAR"

echo $INS   
.           # In each echo command I want to dynamically substitute
.           # the $VAR variable in the $INS variable. I want to do
echo $INS   # the substitution of the variable on echo command.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You need a function to do the job gracefully.

```
say() {
    echo "Installing $INS"
}

INS=hello
say

INS=world
say
```

---

Or just this:

```
say() {
    echo "Installing $@"
}

say hello

say world
```

Comment: A much better solution to the underlying problem, though it doesn't answer the OP's question.  I do wish more people would ask questions about the problems they want to solve rather than the solutions they think they want to implement.

Comment: This look more suitable for my purpose. Thank you.

Comment: @user1405441 - this is the right solution, but be sure to reward with upvotes the answers that actually answered your question.

Comment: @ghoti: You may have seen [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) before, but just in case.

Comment: You are right @ghoti. I want to solve a problem, but I'm also open to learning different methods. I didn't know that I could use functions, that's why I couldn't ask the question correctly. I will upvote you when I have enough reputation :)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - I saw it a while back and haven't been able to remember where.  Thanks!  (Figures it would be on Greg's wiki.)

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat varins
#!/bin/bash

msg='Installing "$VAR"'

for VAR in foo bar baz; do
  eval echo "$msg"
done

[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./varins
Installing foo
Installing bar
Installing baz
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

This relies on the fact that $VAR won't be expanded inside single quotes.  The `eval` command will expand the `$msg` variable, in which the shell will find `$VAR` to replace.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter substitution can do it also:

```
ins='aaa $var aaa'
var='xxx'
echo "'${ins//\$var/$var}'"
```

result:

```
'aaa xxx aaa'
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but when I want to overwrite the variable it doesn't work. When I do it repetedly, I always get the first variable as the output

Answer (score 0):

```
INS='Installing $VAR'
result=`eval "echo $INS"`
echo $result
```

you have to use single quotes to not substitute $VAR on creation of INS
`eval` evaluates $INS at runtime and with `echo` and `backticks` it is returned as substituted string

Comment: You don't need to (and probably shouldn't) run eval in a sub-shell like this.  `eval result="echo \"$INS\""` would do.

Comment: yes would do, but I wanted to separate the solving 'eval'-part from the using 'result='-part to make clear, what solves OPs problem; in general I would prefer kev's function solution anyway

Answer (score -2):

As Hachi said, you need single quotes to prevent $VAR from premature evaluation. Graham suggests in the comments to avoid the subshell call like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=17
INS='Installing $VAR'
eval "echo \"$INS\""
VAR=42
eval "echo \"$INS\""
```

If you don't do it:

```
VAR=23
INS="Installing $VAR"
echo $(eval "echo $INS")
VAR=8
echo $(eval "echo $INS")
```

23 is bound immediately, and the assignment VAR=8 isn't noticed.

Result:

```
Installing 17
Installing 42
Installing 23
Installing 23
```

Comment: As with Hachi, you don't need to (and probably shouldn't) run eval in a sub-shell like this.  `eval "echo \"$INS\""` will do just fine.

Comment: @Graham: Why shouldn't I run eval in a subshell? If you have an alternative solution - why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: A subshell in this case is a waste of a process.  `echo $(echo …)` is pointless. And I don't need to post an answer, because ghoti already posted exactly what I would have posted.